# Is it fine to mine/index SO?

Tags: discussion

It's a tentative question, so I hope you'll go easy on me. I don't know much about it, and I just happened to notice this 4th result of my [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow%20resharper%20check%20my%20code%20only%20when%20I%20press%20enter&rlz=1C1CHBF_svSE999SE999&oq=stackoverflow%20resharper%20check%20my%20code%20only%20when%20I%20press%20enter&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.4480j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

[image: Partial screenshot of a Google search result list]

The link gives a `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` warning instead of a web page.

http://https--stackoverflow--com.proxy.hongze.gov.cn/questions/186970/what-resharper-4-live-templates-for-c-sharp-do-you-use

I'm mostly curious if this is something that should be reported, and if this is some way of mirroring certain sites to where they can be accessed while restricting access outside a country's 'net.

Comment: I would *love* to know what's going on here. Why is a local government site in China seemingly doubling as a Stack Overflow mirror?

Comment: "*Should I report these sites to the Stack Exchange administration? You should only [report the site to us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) if **the site is a proxy**. Whatever the purpose of the site actually is, malicious or not, proxies represent a serious security threat to our site. Sometimes they even start showing up in Google results and users click on them not realizing that they aren't actually on Stack Overflow. Users get confused, or try to log in and accidentally send sensitive information to a third-party service.*" However, I also can't open the page from here.

Comment: For what it's worth, the site linked to does exist.  It's an IPv6 only server, and seems to be a fairly straightforward mirror.  Not that tells you why, but it's really a thing nevertheless.